# Python Tkinter label not moving properly

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

```
label = tk.Label(frame, text=app.split('/')[-1:][0] + "\n", bg="#1c1c1c",
padx=5, pady=5, font=("Helvetica 12 bold"), fg="white")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

This code is supposed to generate labels (Making new labels is done with a separate function) and the labels are supposed to go top to bottom, starting from top left of the window. I would use `label.pack()` however `label.pack()` just makes it go from the middle top to bottom. That's why I'm using `label.grid(row=0, column=0)`. But the problem with that is the new label just replaces the pre-existing one. Is there any way I can fix that are move labels while still using `label.pack()`?

Full function is
def addApps():

```
for widget in frame.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()

filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File", 
filetypes= (("executables", "*.exe"), ("All files", "*.*")))
filename.split('/')[-1:][0]
apps.append(filename)
print("{filename}, {apps}")
for app in apps:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=app.split('/')[-1:][0] + "\n", bg="#1c1c1c",
    padx=5, pady=5, font=("Helvetica 12 bold"), fg="white")
    label.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates the problem. The code you showed only creates a single label in a single place in the window.

Comment: But that's where my problem lies.

Comment: I don’t see anywhere in your code where you are moving widgets. You are just putting them all in the same row and column.

Comment: If you want to actively move widgets (like an animation), I highly recommend using a `tkinter.Canvas` instead of calling `.pack()` or `.grid()`. And when you grid a widget in the same place as the previous one (in this case, `row=0, column=0`), it _will_ replace it. Widgets in the same "square" in `grid()` don't move aside for each other.

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan said, you are just putting the labels on top of each other. Because you don't change the row or column coordinates, the labels are stacked on top of each other and the last label placed is the one you will see on top. You need to change the row in `grid()` to stack them.

The below examples stack your labels from top to bottom, aligned to the left, using both `grid()` and `pack()`

Grid:

```
for label_row, app in enumerate(apps):
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=app.split('/')[-1:][0] + "\n", bg="#1c1c1c",
    padx=5, pady=5, font=("Helvetica 12 bold"), fg="white")
    label.grid(row=label_row, column=0, sticky = tk.NW)
```

Pack:

```
for app in apps:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=app.split('/')[-1:][0] + "\n", bg="#1c1c1c",
    padx=5, pady=5, font=("Helvetica 12 bold"), fg="white")
    label.pack(anchor = tk.NW)
```

I recommend looking up how the `grid()` and `pack()` methods work and the options available for both.